# knockout (template binding) : javascript(JQuery) functions not getting called from inside the template

Tags: jquery, html, knockout.js, templatebinding

I have a main page where i have all the scripts referred and inside the body i have a duv container which has template data binding and my htm's are getting binded in there.

The problem is my functionality which is controlled by Jquery is not working properly.
For e.g. A date picker works when i put it in the main page where JavaScript are referred but doesn't work inside my htm's which are getting binded to the template.

All the libraries are getting loaded properly but my jquery functionality doesn't work when its getting called inside the template.

e.g. 
Main Page:

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery.qtip.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/foundation.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/languageswitcher.js"></script>

<div id="Container" ua-app-id="topVm" data-bind='template: {name: pageModel, data: pageVM }'>                   
</div>
<!-- Initialize JS Plugins -->
<script src="Scripts/app.js"></script>
```

---

Now my view get loaded in the main page at run time. Inside my view i have a date picker, it doesn't work. When i put that out in the main page it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is because your jQuery code is run before your template is rendered. You can use the afterRender callback provided in the template binding to enable enable the datepicker. Look at the [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html#note_4_using_afterrender_afteradd_and_beforeremove) for more information and examples.

But an even better method to accomplish this, is to create a custom binding. Something like this:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.datepicker = {
    init: function(element){
        $(element).datepicker();
    },
    update: function(element) {
        $(element).datepicker('refresh');
    }
};
```

Then you can make text-input into a datepicker by doing this:

```
<input type="text" data-bind="datepicker:true" />
```

Read more about custom bindings [here](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html)

Comment: Can i refer the whole javascript library in custom binding. E.g in the init function() can i call the complete library. Or may be if i can do a event-binding on my main template?
I am asking this because my functions are spread accross libraries and calling everything in custom binding doesn't make sense.
So once the template is loaded if i can re-call the libraries will it be a good way of handling things?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand your question! Can you give an example?

Comment: The problem was from my page which was using knockout it wasn't recognizing the method qtip from jquery.qtip.js. The actual problem was it loading before foundation.min.js. I changed the order and it started working fine. Your date picker solution worked, thanks for that. Just started learning knockout so my questions may sound stupid.